# Problemas com a string de conexão do excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-excel

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código que faz conexão com o Excel, porém me retorna o 
erro:

```
string sFileXLSX = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportPerformanceEntrega"];
string strConnXLSX = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + sFileXLSX + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnXLSX))
{
    //SQL para fazer o Delete

    string strSQL = "DELETE FROM [Base Entregue1$]";
    //Criando o OleDbCommand com o SQL e a conexão
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
    //Abrindo a conexão
    conn.Open();
    //Executando o Delete
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Fechando a conexão
    conn.Close();
}
```

> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine

Porém já instalei o arquivo Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable que era pra corrigir esse erro e mesmo assim continha retornando essa `exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em ambientes de Windows de 64 bits do Office (2010, 2013), há muitos relatos sobre esse erro. A solução ou solução alternativa é um pouco estranha, mas parece funcionar para a maioria das pessoas.

O pacote de instalação "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" parece ser a solução natural, mas vários relatórios dizem que não funciona.

Em vez disso, usando o "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" parece resolver o problema para a maioria das pessoas.

Fonte: https://www.connectionstrings.com/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/

Comment: Agusto Estranhamente funcionou mesmo.

Comment: Que bom cara! :)